# A very basic problem regarding strings that's bugging me

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string s, t;
    cin >> s;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i]!='R' || s[i]!='G' || s[i]!='B'){
        cout << "invalid input1";
        break;

    }


}
}
```

Even if I input a string only containing R, G and B, it shows invalid input! Where am I wrong on the logic?

I expected it not to show invalid input if the string contained R, G and B only.. Like RGBRGRBRBRGRBRGR.. But even if it contains only R,G and B, it shows invalid input. This is part of a bigger Codeforces problem and it's really getting on my nerves that I'm stuck on such a basic section...

Comment: which character you expect to yield `false` for the condition?

Comment: any character is either not `'R'` or not `'B'` because it cannot be both

Comment: "If c is not R **or** c is not G **or** c is not B, then invalid input."  If c is R, then c will **not** be G or B.

Comment: Rethink your logic :-)   R is != G and G is != R and so on. Your binary logic is simply always true :-) Use "&&" instead of "||"

Comment: `bool isRGB(char c) { return c == 'R' || c == 'G' || c == 'B'; }` then `if (!isRGB(s[i]))` and the code becomes easier to understand.

Comment: This is a common logical trap; the negation of "X is A or X is B" is not "X is not A or X is not B".

Comment: Once you get the condition right, consider starting to play with [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) or [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of).

Comment: For reference, the relevant boolean logic here is De Morgan's law ( https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/csjava/Unit3-If-Statements/topic-3-6-DeMorgan.html ) which says that e.g. `if (!a && !b && !c)` can be rewritten as `if !(a || b || c)` without changing its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You're using OR operators.

If your string is `R`, then `s[i]!='G'` evaluates to `true`, and because you're using OR operators, you get `invalid output`

Comment: And the fix is ...

Comment: The fix should be replacing the OR by AND

Comment: @SKCoder -- indeed; the point of my comment was to suggest that that should be in the answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker OP didn't ask what the fix is, they asked what the problem is. I don't think it's helpful to spell out every detail in an answer because it doesn't help anyone learn to think critically if they're given everything up front. If OP came back and asked "how do I fix it?" then I'd be happy to engage.

Comment: @Chuck -- don't be so bloddyl-minded. -1.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
if(s[i]!='R' || s[i]!='G' || s[i]!='B')
```

with

```
if(!(s[i]=='R' || s[i]=='G' || s[i]=='B'))
```